# Expected Value of Joint pdf

Tags: statistics

Given the pdf of $f(x,y) = 8xy$ if $0 < x < y < 1$, and simply $0$ otherwise, 
how would you calculate $E(XY^3)$? I understand how to calculate $E(XY)$ but I am uncertain about what extra steps would be required in this case.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain how you find $E[XY]$ first?

Comment: @Johnny What is the joint pdf of (X,Y) or what are the marginal pdf's of X and Y (and the relation between them)?

Answer (score 1):

You do it almost exactly like $E(XY)$. We need to integrate $(xy^3)(8xy)$ over the right region.

Draw the region. It is the triangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(0,1)$.

If you choose to integrate first with respect to $x$, then $x$ goes from $0$ to $y$.

If you choose to integrate first with respect to $y$ (not best) then $y$ goes from $x$ to $1$.